# react native API call from view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app I am doing like this -

In my `APICall.js` I have -

```
export const myAPICall = async () => {
    const reqOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
    };

    let response = fetch('https://...', reqOptions);
    return response;
}
```

I have my `View.js` where, I have -

```
 import {myAPICall} from './APICall';

     gotoView2 = (apiMethod) => {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('View2', { apiMethod: apiMethod });
     }

   render() {
       return(
             <TouchableOpacity

                    onPress={() => this.gotoView2 (myAPICall)}>
                    <Text>Welcome</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
           )
       }
```

where apiMethod is myAPICall

In my `View2.js`, I have -

```
doCall = async() => {
 let response = await this.props.navigation.state.params.apiMethod();
 }
```

But nothing happens. I want to make API call from my View2.js but seems not possible. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you see if you console.log in view2: `console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.apiMethod)`?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: Add where you use `gotoView2`

Comment: please check..I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
export const myAPICall = async () => {
    const reqOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
    };

    let response = await fetch('https://...', reqOptions);
    return response;
}


import {myAPICall} from './APICall';

 gotoView2 = () => {
   myAPICall().then((returnData) => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('View2', { data: returnData });
   });
 
 }

   render() {
   return(
         <TouchableOpacity

                onPress={() => this.gotoView2()}>
                <Text>Welcome</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
       )
   }
```

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: You can catch data in view2 from props. (this.props.navigation.state.params.data)